# How to keep scroll position after adding new elements on top of the list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

scroll position of listview changed if I add multiple elements from top in list. It's working fine for insert operation when we inster new elements in the bottom of the list.

Usecase is there is one chat module in my application & I have to implement both side pagination (up & down) in  that. If user scroll up then normal pagination flow, items added in the bottom of the list so it's working fine. But if user user scroll down then new items added at the top of the list & scroll position changed.

I have searched in all place & tried all solution but didn't found any proper solution & many people also faced the same issue.

I am attaching a one dartpad link of this issue : [open dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=8547176e14b4b49218c3da60ba5ac41c)

Step to reproduce:

- run the app, scroll to end of the list
- now click on add icon, it will add 30 items in top of the list & you will notice scroll position will change after that
- in this example I'm using setState but the same thing will happen even after using any state management solution.
- I'm expecting not to change scroll position if I add elements from top of the list

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the problem is that the viewport would layout its slivers using the new maxScrollExtent (that increased due to the newly added items). However, the `ScrollPosition.pixels` is still unchanged, while existing slivers have received their new scroll offset in their `SliverGeometry`.

Consequently, slivers would paint their items using the new scroll offset and the old `ScrollPosition.pixels` (that would be updated once the painting is completed for the current frame).

Therefore, we have three ways to align the new scroll offset and the old pixels.

1. Comparing the diff between the old and new max scroll extent, and `jumpTo(diff)` using `addPostFrameCallback`, like below:

```dart
    final double old = _controller.position.pixels;
    final double oldMax = _controller.position.maxScrollExtent;

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (old > 0.0) {
        final diff = _controller.position.maxScrollExtent - oldMax;
        _controller.jumpTo(old + diff);
      }
    });
```

This way would meet your requirements but the painting may flicker between the two frames since you actually do `JumpTo` normally. See [the video link](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/55259373/226113783-e8661960-fbca-4330-83bb-d75db5e7362e.mp4).

2. Align the pixel difference during the layout phase. This way would extend the `ScrollController` and create a custom `ScrollPosition` to align the pixel difference when the viewport invokes `ViewportOffset.applyContentDimensions` during `performLayout()`. Eventually, you could invoke `RetainableScrollController.retainOffset()` to keep the scroll position when inserting new items at the top of the list view.

```dart
class RetainableScrollController extends ScrollController {
  RetainableScrollController({
    super.initialScrollOffset,
    super.keepScrollOffset,
    super.debugLabel,
  });

  @override
  ScrollPosition createScrollPosition(
    ScrollPhysics physics,
    ScrollContext context,
    ScrollPosition? oldPosition,
  ) {
    return RetainableScrollPosition(
      physics: physics,
      context: context,
      initialPixels: initialScrollOffset,
      keepScrollOffset: keepScrollOffset,
      oldPosition: oldPosition,
      debugLabel: debugLabel,
    );
  }

  void retainOffset() {
    position.retainOffset();
  }

  @override
  RetainableScrollPosition get position =>
      super.position as RetainableScrollPosition;
}

class RetainableScrollPosition extends ScrollPositionWithSingleContext {
  RetainableScrollPosition({
    required super.physics,
    required super.context,
    super.initialPixels = 0.0,
    super.keepScrollOffset,
    super.oldPosition,
    super.debugLabel,
  });

  double? _oldPixels;
  double? _oldMaxScrollExtent;

  bool get shouldRestoreRetainedOffset =>
      _oldMaxScrollExtent != null && _oldPixels != null;

  void retainOffset() {
    if (!hasPixels) return;
    _oldPixels = pixels;
    _oldMaxScrollExtent = maxScrollExtent;
  }

  /// when the viewport layouts its children, it would invoke [applyContentDimensions] to
  /// update the [minScrollExtent] and [maxScrollExtent].
  /// When it happens, [shouldRestoreRetainedOffset] would determine if correcting the current [pixels],
  /// so that the final scroll offset is matched to the previous items' scroll offsets.
  /// Therefore, avoiding scrolling down/up when the new item is inserted into the first index of the list.
  @override
  bool applyContentDimensions(double minScrollExtent, double maxScrollExtent) {
    final applied =
        super.applyContentDimensions(minScrollExtent, maxScrollExtent);

    bool isPixelsCorrected = false;

    if (shouldRestoreRetainedOffset) {
      final diff = maxScrollExtent - _oldMaxScrollExtent!;
      if (_oldPixels! > minScrollExtent && diff > 0) {
        correctPixels(pixels + diff);
        isPixelsCorrected = true;
      }
      _oldMaxScrollExtent = null;
      _oldPixels = null;
    }

    return applied && !isPixelsCorrected;
  }
}
```

The demo video could be found [[here]](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/55259373/226113863-d8bf16ec-da82-4985-85c4-e0db3685008c.mp4)

3. The best way to achieve your goal is to use a special `ScrollPhysics`. Though this way, you do not need to change your existing codes, and just pass `physics: const PositionRetainedScrollPhysics()` in your list view.

```dart
class PositionRetainedScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  final bool shouldRetain;
  const PositionRetainedScrollPhysics({super.parent, this.shouldRetain = true});

  @override
  PositionRetainedScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return PositionRetainedScrollPhysics(
      parent: buildParent(ancestor),
      shouldRetain: shouldRetain,
    );
  }

  @override
  double adjustPositionForNewDimensions({
    required ScrollMetrics oldPosition,
    required ScrollMetrics newPosition,
    required bool isScrolling,
    required double velocity,
  }) {
    final position = super.adjustPositionForNewDimensions(
      oldPosition: oldPosition,
      newPosition: newPosition,
      isScrolling: isScrolling,
      velocity: velocity,
    );

    final diff = newPosition.maxScrollExtent - oldPosition.maxScrollExtent;

    if (oldPosition.pixels > oldPosition.minScrollExtent &&
        diff > 0 &&
        shouldRetain) {
      return position + diff;
    } else {
      return position;
    }
  }
}
```

> you could also use [positioned_scroll_observer](https://pub.dev/packages/positioned_scroll_observer) to use the `PositionRetainedScrollPhysics` and also other functions, like scrolling to a specific index in any scroll view.

Comment: be aware that the solution No 3 does not work with CustomScrollView and slivers as in that situation maxScrollExtent is always changing, still looking for a solution

Comment: "  ScrollPosition.pixels is still unchanged  " .. not true .. it change immediately

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and give the physics to your listview.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PositionRetainedScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  final bool shouldRetain;
  const PositionRetainedScrollPhysics(
      {ScrollPhysics? parent, this.shouldRetain = true})
      : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  PositionRetainedScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return PositionRetainedScrollPhysics(
      parent: buildParent(ancestor),
      shouldRetain: shouldRetain,
    );
  }

  @override
  double adjustPositionForNewDimensions({
    required ScrollMetrics oldPosition,
    required ScrollMetrics newPosition,
    required bool isScrolling,
    required double velocity,
  }) {
    final position = super.adjustPositionForNewDimensions(
      oldPosition: oldPosition,
      newPosition: newPosition,
      isScrolling: isScrolling,
      velocity: velocity,
    );

    final diff = newPosition.maxScrollExtent - oldPosition.maxScrollExtent;
    if (oldPosition.pixels == 0) {
      if (newPosition.maxScrollExtent > oldPosition.maxScrollExtent &&
          diff > 0 &&
          shouldRetain) {
        return diff;
      } else {
        return position;
      }
    } else {
      return position;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need one more function called `scrollTop` that needs to call inside `_incrementCounter` function

```
void scrollTop() {
    controller.animateTo(
      0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    );
  }
```

**Demo:**

[image]

**Below is fixed your code example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> listItem = [];
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 30; i >= 0; i--) {
      listItem.add('Message -------> $i');
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    final startIndex = listItem.length - 1;
    final endIndex = listItem.length + 30;
    for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
      listItem.insert(0, 'Message -------> $i');
    }

    setState(() {});
    scrollTop();
  }

  void scrollTop() {
    controller.animateTo(
      0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listItem.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        controller: controller,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          height: 50,
          width: 100,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              listItem[index],
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it's just an example, in real-world applications I have this problem with chat screen & I can not move to top of the list I need to keep scroll position where user has seen last message before adding other messages on top.

If I calculate the offset & move to that specific position then also it's a very bad user experience for a user. It looks like jank in the list.

Answer (score -1):

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKU1u.gif)

I've made a little tweak to accomplish this behavior

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

enum ITEM_TYPE { main, sub, hidden }

const ITEM_COUNT = 10;

final _random = Random();
double randomHeight(int min, int max) =>
    min + _random.nextInt(max - min).toDouble();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo List View'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<double> heights =
      List.generate(ITEM_COUNT, (index) => randomHeight(50, 150));

  //* This is the main items
  List<int> mainItems = List.generate(ITEM_COUNT, (index) => index + 1);
  List<GlobalKey> mainKeys = List.generate(ITEM_COUNT, (index) => GlobalKey());

  //* This is the sub items used to show when loading prev (always clone from main items)
  List<int> subItems = [];

  //* This is the hidden items used to calculate the whole new offset of new main items (fetch from loading prev)
  List<int> hiddenItems = [];
  List<GlobalKey> hiddenKeys = [];

  final _scrollController = ScrollController();

  bool isLoadingMore = false;
  bool isLoadingPrev = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    subItems = List<int>.from(mainItems);

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      final canLoadMore = _scrollController.offset >=
              _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
          !_scrollController.position.outOfRange &&
          !isLoadingMore;

      final canLoadPrev = _scrollController.offset <=
              _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent &&
          !_scrollController.position.outOfRange &&
          !isLoadingPrev;

      if (canLoadMore) {
        _loadMore();
      }

      if (canLoadPrev) {
        _loadPrev();
      }
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: mainItems.isNotEmpty
          ? Stack(
              children: [
                _hiddenWidget(),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    if (isLoadingMore)
                      const LinearProgressIndicator(minHeight: 2),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          _mainWidget(context),
                          _subWidget(context),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    if (isLoadingPrev)
                      Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                        child: const CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 2),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )
          : const SizedBox(),
      floatingActionButton: _refreshWidget(),
    );
  }

  FloatingActionButton _refreshWidget() {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        mainItems = List.generate(ITEM_COUNT, (index) => index + 1);
        heights = List.generate(ITEM_COUNT, (index) => randomHeight(50, 150));
        mainKeys = List.generate(ITEM_COUNT, (index) => GlobalKey());

        subItems = List<int>.from(mainItems);

        hiddenItems = [];
        hiddenKeys = [];

        _scrollController.jumpTo(0.1);
        setState(() {});
      },
      child: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.refresh),
    );
  }

  Expanded _subWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: !isLoadingPrev ? 0 : 1,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: !isLoadingPrev ? 0 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: ListView.builder(
          reverse: true,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return _itemContainer(
              index: index,
              type: ITEM_TYPE.sub,
            );
          },
          itemCount: subItems.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Expanded _mainWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: isLoadingPrev ? 0 : 1,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: isLoadingPrev ? 0 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: ListView.builder(
          reverse: true,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          controller: _scrollController,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return _itemContainer(
              index: index,
              type: ITEM_TYPE.main,
            );
          },
          itemCount: mainItems.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Positioned _hiddenWidget() {
    return Positioned.fill(
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      child: Offstage(
        offstage: true,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          reverse: true,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: hiddenItems
                .mapIndexed(
                  (index, element) => _itemContainer(
                    index: index,
                    type: ITEM_TYPE.hidden,
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container _itemContainer({required int index, required ITEM_TYPE type}) {
    Key? key;
    int text = -1;

    switch (type) {
      case ITEM_TYPE.main:
        key = mainKeys[index];
        text = mainItems[index];
        break;

      case ITEM_TYPE.hidden:
        key = hiddenKeys[index];
        text = hiddenItems[index];
        break;

      case ITEM_TYPE.sub:
        text = subItems[index];
        break;

      default:
    }

    return Container(
      key: key,
      color: index % 2 == 0
          ? Colors.lightBlueAccent.withOpacity(0.2)
          : Colors.tealAccent.withOpacity(0.2),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: heights[index],
      child: Text(text.toString()),
    );
  }

  void _loadMore() {
    if (isLoadingMore || isLoadingPrev) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      isLoadingMore = true;
    });

    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) {
      for (var i = 0; i < ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
        mainItems.add(mainItems.last + 1);
        mainKeys.add(GlobalKey());
        heights.add(randomHeight(50, 150));
      }

      setState(() {});
      isLoadingMore = false;
      subItems = List<int>.from(mainItems);
    });
  }

  void _loadPrev() {
    if (isLoadingMore || isLoadingPrev) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      isLoadingPrev = true;
    });

    double initialPosition = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    hiddenItems = [];
    hiddenKeys = [];
    double adjustment = 0.0;

    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) {
      for (var i = 0; i < ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
        mainItems.insert(0, mainItems[0] - 1);
        mainKeys.insert(0, GlobalKey());

        hiddenItems.insert(0, mainItems[0] - 1);
        hiddenKeys.insert(0, GlobalKey());

        heights.add(randomHeight(50, 150));
      }

      setState(() {});

      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
          RenderBox renderBox =
              hiddenKeys[i].currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          adjustment += renderBox.size.height;
        }

        // Set the scroll position back to its original value
        _scrollController.jumpTo(initialPosition + adjustment);

        Future.microtask(() {
          setState(() {
            isLoadingPrev = false;
            subItems = List<int>.from(mainItems);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Copy and paste this in your main.dart

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).